# Duel Boot Windows 10 on an SSD and ubuntu on 260gb of 1TB HD Issue

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I have an Acer Aspire E-15 notebook with a 128GB SSD drive and a 1tb Hard drive. It has Windows 10 Home installed on the SSD drive. I turned off secure boot (the computer is in UEFI mode) and installed ubuntu 18.04 from a bootable memory stick.
During the installation I chose, install along side my current OS. It only saw the Hard drive, I told it to take 200GB of that drive and it installed with no issues. When I rebooted I did not get the boot menu. I check the boot order and Window Boot Manager was number 1. I changed the Hard Drive to number 1 and it still boots to Windows.
Thank you for any help you can offer,

Mace

Comment: Almost all Acer need UEFI update and many SSD need firmware update. And many Acer need "trust" set in UEFI on ubuntu/grub .efi boot files. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947 &

Answer (score 0):

The comment above answered the question.

I did step 35 and below. I can now boot to the GRUB menu using the F12 key.

thanks,

Mace